# Creating Dictionary C# with custom type passed by function

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to create a Dictionary with TKey as string and the TValue to be from type which is not know at compile time.

Let's say for example I have a function

```
 createDict(Type type)
 {
     Dictionary<string, {here's the type from the func. argument}> dict = new Dictionary..

 }
```

Is this scenario possible or I'm missing something very basic ?

Comment: How is your type determined? People seem to be upvoting the generics solution without regard to your statement of not knowing the type at compile time (closed generics without reflection *need* the type at compile time). If you can show us how the type is determined, the answers can be better tailored to your issue.

Comment: It seems to me that the type is determined from the "Type" parameter passed to createDict()

Comment: @MatthewWatson Obviously, but I was trying to ascertain if it was truly needed versus knowing the type at compile time. Reflecting a generic dictionary where you don't know the type seems odd to me, in the face of `Dictionary<string, object>` or even `Hashtable`.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit odd. Actually using the created dictionary won't be very straightforward, either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the method generic:

```
public void CreateDict<T>()
{
    Dictionary<string,T> dict = new Dictionary<string,T>();

}
```

Though you may want the return type to also be `Dictionary<string,T>` and add constrains to the generic type parameter.

You would call it as:

```
CreateDict<MyCustomType>();
```

The above assumes the type can be passed in during compile time.

Comment: Just a note - this assumes the type is known at compile time (from the caller's perspective).

Answer (score 4):

It can be done if you pass type as a parameter:

```
var dictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string),type);
var dictionary = (IDictionary)Activator.CreateInstance(dictionaryType);
```

usage of such dictionary will be harder due to you take full responsibility on correctness of what is inserted to this dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can do with a bit of reflection:

```
Type dict = typeof (Dictionary<,>);
Type[] parameters = {typeof (string), type};
Type parametrizedDict = dict.MakeGenericType(parameters);
object result = Activator.CreateInstance(parametrizedDict);
```

Comment: @Oded The OP states "not known at compile time", but without any details of how the type is determined, no one can know if either reflection or generics are suitable.

Comment: @Oded, is it? I must be missing something, but post author stated that _type which is not know at compile time_.

Comment: Rather than 'typeof(type)' in that code, you should just use 'type' shouldn't you? (i.e. just use the 'type' parameter passed to the OP's createDict() method)

Answer (score 1):

all instances and classes are objects, so why not `Dictionary<string,object>` and you do cast the same way you do with ViewData in MVC, Session or Cache, all of them need the cast.

Answer (score 1):

Use generics if type is known at compile time:

```
void Main()
{
    var dict = CreateDict<int>();
    dict["key"] = 10;
}

Dictionary<string, T> CreateDict<T>()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, T>();
}
```

If not, refactor to use a base type or interface e.g:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, IMyType>();
```

where IMyType exposes the common traits of the type that you wish to keep in the dictionary.

Only as a last resort would I look to reflection.

Comment: Just a note - this assumes the type is known at compile time (from the caller's perspective).

Comment: That is correct. If the type is unknown at compile time, I guess the way to go is reflection. Usually though this is of a sign a problematic design. I edited my post to reflect this